# usings static buttons to access different view controllers views

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

As the titles states I am looking to have a main view controller with a few buttons.  Depending on which button was pressed I would like to load a view of a separate view controller in a contained field below the buttons where I can still access the buttons and the content in the view.  How should I attempt to accomplish this?

Comment: I found the solution [here](http://www.allappsdevelopers.com/TopicDetail.aspx?TopicID=c18ec126-ac4a-441d-afbc-bddf8e6d35f6). Thank you for the responses.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is add the viewcontroller's view as you would any other view. So it would look something like;

```
ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] init...];
[vc.view setFrame:whatever frame you want];
[self.view addSubview:vc];
```

And just have that called in your button's action method.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for a [`UITabBarController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/TabBarControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH3-SW1)